# File manager multifunction on openbox

Tags: arch-linux, openbox, file-manager

I've just installed ArchLinux with only OpenBox, I need a file manager and a programme to manage the icons on the desktop. I read that PacManFM can do that, which other filemanager can do each task together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you have settled on a solution in the meantime, but just for the record, [Rox](http://rox.sourceforge.net/desktop/about_rox.html) is another application that combines a (very quick but slightly idiosyncratic) file manager with desktop functionality.